# Why do we have to use exact DataOutputStream to transfer textual data?

Tags: java, outputstream

I have a client-server application where the client is:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 12345);
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println(r.readLine());
        s.close();
    }
```

and the server:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(12345);
    Socket client = server.accept();
    OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
    //DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(out);
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(out));
    writer.write("String on client's behalf"); //Prints null on the client side. Why?
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    client.close();
}
```

But if we write the following:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(12345);
    Socket client = server.accept();
    OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(out);
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(dout));
    writer.write("String on client's behalf"); //Prints exact what I expected.
    dout.flush();
    dout.close();
    client.close();
}
```

I can't get the point of that differences. What the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) says is

> This abstract class is the superclass of all classes representing an
>   output stream of bytes. An output stream accepts output bytes and
>   sends them to some sink.

Well, I just used a subclass of the `abstract class` to transfer data from the server. What's wrong?

Comment: Why don't you close the buffer?

Comment: @Basilevs You mean `writer.close()`? It didn't change anything.

Comment: @St.Antario were you calling `writer.close()` before or after `out.close()`?

Comment: @immibis Yes, I did. Now it works fine. That's a real magic to me. could you explain that?

Comment: @St.Antario do you know what `BufferedWriter` does?

Comment: @immibis It writes data into an output stream it binded. First it writes this date into a local buffer and after the buffer is completed it'll send it into the stream. Is it right?

Comment: @St.Antario Yes... it also writes the buffered data when it's closed or flushed. The default buffer size is several kilobytes, so you don't write enough to fill the buffer. Then you close the stream without giving the `BufferedWriter` a chance to write what it buffered.

Comment: @immibis Ah, that's what the problem was! I got it, thank you.

Comment: @immibis Could you write an answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `BufferedWriter` stores anything you `write` to it in a buffer. It writes it to the underlying stream when the buffer is full, or when it is flushed or closed.

Your code writes to the `BufferedWriter`. It doesn't write enough to fill the buffer, and it never flushes or closes the `BufferedWriter`, so the `BufferedWriter` never writes the buffered data to the underlying stream (the `PrintWriter`).

Then you close `out`, before anything has been written to `out`.

If you change `out.close()` to `writer.close()` in your first code snippet, it works.

This is one reason it is important to close streams. If you close `writer`, it will flush the buffer and close the `PrintWriter` (which will close `out`). Note that closing a stream flushes it - you don't need to call `flush` separately.

I have no idea why your second code snippet supposedly works. My best guess is that that is not the exact code you tried.

Comment: 2nd code snippet works because the `DataOutputStream` is being closed. Even if it wasn't being closed, it isn't buffered.

Comment: @EJP The second code snippet has a `BufferedWriter` wrapping a `PrintWriter` wrapping a `DataOutputStream` wrapping the socket's output stream.

Comment: @EJP I agree with immibis, it's not clear to me why the second example works fine. As you truly metioned it was wrapped into a BufferedWriter. Could you provide any normative refrences to javadoc about that issue?